# How to get GPS location in Acumatica Mobile App?

Tags: acumatica

Our customer has a request to record GPS location in Appointments screen when technician starts a drive to the site.
I added a new action to AppointmentEntry graph (basically it is a copy of StartAppointment action with some code removed) and added this action to mobile app. The problem is that fsAppointmentCopy.Mem_GPSLatitudeLongitude is null when my custom action invoked on mobile app, but it has a value when "Start Appointment" action is invoked. What am I missing?

```
    public PXAction<PX.Objects.FS.FSAppointment> StartDrive;

[PXButton]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Start Drive", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
protected virtual IEnumerable startDrive(PXAdapter adapter)
{
        List<FSAppointment> list = adapter.Get<FSAppointment>().ToList();
        foreach (FSAppointment fsAppointmentRow in list)
        {
            Base.SaveBeforeApplyAction(Base.AppointmentRecords.Cache, fsAppointmentRow);

            FSAppointment fsAppointmentCopy = (FSAppointment)Base.Caches[typeof(FSAppointment)].CreateCopy(fsAppointmentRow);


            var fsAppointmentDetRows = Base.AppointmentDetServices.SelectWindowed(0, 1);

            if (fsAppointmentDetRows.Count == 0)
            {
                throw new PXException(TX.Error.APPOINTMENT_START_VALIDATE_SERVICE, PXErrorLevel.Error);
            }

            using (var ts = new PXTransactionScope())
            {

                if (Base.IsMobile == true
                        && Base.SetupRecord.Current != null
                            && Base.SetupRecord.Current.TrackAppointmentLocation == true
                                && string.IsNullOrEmpty(fsAppointmentCopy.Mem_GPSLatitudeLongitude) == false)
                {
                    string[] parts = fsAppointmentCopy.Mem_GPSLatitudeLongitude.Split(':');
                    fsAppointmentCopy.GPSLatitudeStart = decimal.Parse(parts[0]);
                    fsAppointmentCopy.GPSLongitudeStart = decimal.Parse(parts[1]);
                }

                Base.ChangeStatusSave(fsAppointmentCopy);

                ts.Complete();
            }

        }
        return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sample "Start Drive" action worked for me (with slight modifications to make it work with most recent Acumatica version):
[image: field has non-null value in debugger]

A couple of things worth checking:

- Double check that mobile Acumatica app was granted access to location. (on iOS: Settings / Acumatica / Location)
- Are you sure your code runs to the point when it reads coordinates from the field? It may fail during record save (some fields are not filled) or when validating that at least one detail line is present
- Make sure that mobile screen mapping still contains definition for `"OtherInformationSourceInfoLocation#GPSLatitudeLongitude"` with `special = GpsCoords`

Comment: Thank you Ivan, I use Android phone and Acumatica mobile app has access to Location, as I mentioned "StartAppointment" action records coordinates just fine. Where can i check this mapping? "OtherInformationSourceInfoLocation#GPSLatitudeLongitude" with special = GpsCoords. These are the changes to appointments screen in update screen FS300200 {
update container "AppointmentRecords" {
  add recordAction "StartDriveMenuActions" {
      behavior = Record
    } 
}
}

Comment: To check the mapping - in customization project editor, open the script for FS300200. You should be able to find field in the Result Preview: OtherInformationSourceInfoLocation#GPSLatitudeLongitude

Comment: Also, please check that you are using latest version of app from Play Store. If nothing helps, share your entire customization package, the problem may be somewhere else.